# How to stream on demand video with load balancing

Tags: stream, nginx, rtmp, ondemand

I am triyng to figure out how to load balance my video server. 
The real world scenario is;

> i have a storage server which stores all my video files, an several
>   servers to load balance my http request(works like a CDN service).
>   Client requests a video file -> Nearest Load balancing server
>   answers request (lets say it LBS) LBS -> Storage (find the video and
>   start sending first N kbyte to client, so it starts to play) -> LBS caches the rest of the
>   file on its own storage, and on the next request, serves it directly
>   from its cache,not from storage.

The problem with this setup is, i want to serve videos through RTMP, but on the balancing machine(its nginx web server), i couldnt serve the virtual files(like rtmp stream).

For the short; i am looking for an rtmp server implementation that acts like an nginx web server. Any ideas, advices will be great.

Note: currently i am trying to implement **crtmpserver**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use nginx_rtmp module ... It's support stream flv files as rtmp streams (and transcoding rtmp streams, and repackage rtmp to hls too)

See doc about: https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/

j

Comment: you are right, i am using nginx rtmp module for 2 months now, and its really successful, thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

nginx created for handle static files.

For rtmp streamig and balansing use [erlyvideo](http://erlyvideo.org/) server. It written on erlang so load balancing are built in by design.

Comment: nginx can handle rtmp too anymore, check out nginx_rtmp_module

Comment: I know about this module but this module hard to customise. I prefer erlang based solutions for hiload projects.